# How to open new terminal and run a command from the current terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I was writing the following alias in `.bashrc`

```
alias ss='gnome-terminal; echo Starting Server;'
```

I was intending to run `ss` on one terminal (T1) and allow `echo Starting Server` to run on another terminal (T2). Though T2 opens the command gets executed on T1. How to make it run on T2?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this command:

`gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'echo Starting Server; sleep 10'`

And if you want keep your terminal open after 10 seconds, you should do :

`gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'echo Starting Server; sleep 10; exec bash'`

You can find a similar answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373186/open-gnome-terminal-window-and-execute-2-commands/373188#373188